# Change Drupal interface language back to English

Tags: i18n-l10n

I made the mistake to translate the Drupal interface in my local language. But since the language is set into the database, I can't delete this language using the Drupal UI. And I'm not sure which file(s) to delete in the database.

Does anyone know a (faultlessly) way to translate the Drupal interface back to English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the language back to English by adding this to the url of any page:

```
&language=en
```

EDIT:

To have a seperate admin and front end language I'd suggest looking at the Admin Language module - http://drupal.org/project/admin_language

SECOND EDIT:

To do this via role have a look at this page - http://deglos.com/blog/2010/06/12/overriding-language-drupal-backend

They are doing what you want with a custom module. You could throw in the user role code there using the global $user.

Comment: That's something I don't want... The language was English by default and I want to delete my new language so English will be the default Drupal UI language.

Comment: Oh ok. Can't you just go to admin/settings/language and click the delete button?

Comment: Yes, but won't this action delete the whole site set in that language?

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry. You just want the site in one language and the UI in the other? I've edited my answer...

Comment: Ok, great module! But I can't get my users (a separate role) use this module (despite setting the permissions!). Only the admin users gets a translation.

Comment: So you have a user role that can access the admin theme(?) that isn't "admin" that you also want the translation to work for?

Comment: Yes. I have a role which has access to the admin theme, but isn't the admin and I do want them to be able to see the UI in English.

Comment: Ok have edited again. It's not my code and I've not tested it but it looks like it will work for you with minimal editing.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what they mean... I can't really figure it out. They use the same function twice... And where do I place the `global $user`?

Comment: Ok, I found the option to use the admin language on the menu in the admin language module! Thanks!

Comment: I know this is a long time later, but I just had to do exactly this. I didn't want to retain the translations and then tell Drupal to ignore them, I wanted to remove them altogether.

I started by disabling the regular updates of the interface translations, and then removed the folder containing the .po files for the different interface translations. Then, I emptied the locales_target table in the database. Since it was now empty, the site not longer shows the interface translations for different languages.